# Failed to build gem native extension with JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, bundler, jrubyonrails

I change the ruby version from ruby 1.9.3-p125 to JRuby 1.7.0-preview1 with [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build). When I execute `jruby -S bundle install` on my project, there are some errors as below,

```
...
Using bson (1.6.2) 
Installing bson_ext (1.6.2) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/joshchang/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.0-preview1/bin/jruby extconf.rb 
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.

   (root) at /Users/joshchang/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.0-preview1/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:991
   (root) at /Users/joshchang/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.0-preview1/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
   (root) at extconf.rb:1
...
```

Is there any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`JRUBY_OPTS="-Xcext.enabled=true" gem install <your gem>` should work!

Answer (score 0):

just read the error message and try as it says: `jruby -Xcext.enabled=true -S bundle install`
although it probably won't work - generally C extensions are not supported on JRuby.

Comment: you do need to review your bundle dependencies, find out why is the **bson_ext** gem being used (`gem 'bson'` alone should be fine on JRuby) and disable it or declare it to be platform dependent e.g. `gem 'bson_ext', :platform => :ruby`. but this is all guessing if you shown us your Gemfile we could probably resolve this ...